# A question regarding a number theory problem

Tags: number-theory

Q: Find every pair of primes $p, q$, such that $pq | (5^p - 2^q)(5^q - 2^p)$

I've tried all I could think of and still could not find a solution. Any help (solution or a hint) would be much appreciated! Thanks.

EDIT: The correction to the problem has been issued, so the task is now corrected to: "Find all pairs of prime numbers $p, q$ such that $pq | (5^p - 2^p)(5^q - 2^q)$."

The problem is now very solvable (I will post a very brief sketch of solution below). I'm sorry it turned out it was an error. I am still very thankful for your help. Thanks!

1. For all positive integers $a, b$ and $c = gcd(a, b)$, we can prove that $gcd((5^a - 2^a), (5^b - 2^b)) = 5^c - 2^c$
2. The case $p | (5^q - 2^q)$ and $q | (5^p - 2^p)$ implies at least one of $p,q$ is equal to $3$ or that $p | q - 1$ and $q | p - 1$, which is contradictory.
3. It follows that at least one of $p, q$ has to equal $3$ and the rest is trivial.

Comment: Note that $p=3, q=41$ works (as does $p=q=3$)

Comment: What is the context here?  Is there any reason to believe that there is a pleasant answer?

Comment: Fermat’s Little Theorem might help…?

Comment: @RyanShesler $p,q \ne 2$ as $(5^p - 2^q)(5^q - 2^p)$  is odd while the $pq$ would be even.

Comment: Can you supply any context at all?  Is this a homework problem?  If not, where did it come from?

Comment: @lulu yeah, it is. pretty sure it's supposed to be solved with Euler's theorem/Fermat's little theorem, I just have no idea how

Comment: I don't see any simple congruence method which would exclude solutions (and the example of $(3,41)$ tends to suggest that there won't be one.  That said, a (fairly casual) search didn't turn up any other examples.  Perhaps there are not many solutions.

Comment: @lulu I know, I thought I was going insane when I didn't find something that could limit the search for solutions. That being said, I'm still pretty sure something like that should exist. If not, I'm wasting everyone's time here.

Comment: Looks like a contest problem. Compare with [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384107/do-there-exist-infinitely-many-pairs-of-primes-p-q-such-that-pq-divides-2).